# Is this image about child teeth development accurate?

Tags: biology, children, dentistry

There's a [picture on Pinterest](http://pinterest.com/pin/147704062749322384/) depicting a child's skull with all [deciduous teeth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deciduous_teeth) (baby teeth) still attached, and adult teeth showing in a quite developed stage underneath:

[image: picture described as a child's skull on Pinterest, originally from the Tobokoz photoblog]

The picture is described as "A child’s skull before losing baby teeth". The point of displaying the picture seems to be that it's expected to be scary or disgusting - repulsive to the audience. This raises doubts about whether it is accurate, or an image that has been edited, or where context has been altered for shock value.

**Is this image accurate** (as a representation of a child's skull during normal teeth development)?

Comment: According to the [FAQ](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/faq#questions), Skeptics.SE is for researching the evidence behind the claims you hear or read. This question doesn't appear to have any doubtful claims to investigate. Please edit it to reference a notable claim and flag for moderator attention to re-open (or get 5 re-open votes).

Comment: By the way the answer is yes :)

Comment: @Sklivvz The claim is that the image represents normal child teeth development. The thing that's doubtful about the claim is that it's a "shocker" image (which basically means it looks surprising in common sense) that's posted on an internet picture board. I understand that those are often fake. (In style of e.g. the [shark jump image](http://www.snopes.com/photos/animals/shark.asp) ) But yeah, I wasn't all that sure the question is suitable for the site myself either.

Comment: I don't understand what is so scary looking about it? I remember seeing something very similar in my own dental x-rays when I was a child. I thought it was pretty interesting. See [here](http://goldriverpediatricdentistry.com/db.php?prod_name=Children%20X-Rays) and [here](http://images.google.com/search?tbm=isch&hl=en&source=hp&biw=1600&bih=1139&q=child+dental+x+ray). @Sklivvz I also think it is an on topic question for the site.

Comment: @SamIAm Well, at least it's clearly indicated to be scary looking on the site. It's all those teeth, you know, anything with lots of teeth in multiple layers is considered frightening. For good reasons, too. :)

Comment: I'll let someone else determine whether it's on topic. I think it is, but not with a lot of confidence.

Comment: I think this question should be re-opened. It has a falsifiable claim, and there's a reasonable suspicion of mis-information (as opposed to merely asking a very technical question).

Comment: I also don't understand why it looks scary, but the depiction is accurate. The secondary teeth develop in the jaw and cut through the gums, or erupt when the roots of the baby teeth dissolve, or resorb; also known as exfoliation. Where else would the permanent teeth come from?

Comment: It also makes me feel uneasy. I suppose having "useless matter" (I can't think of any way to phrase it better) waiting in our body is unconsciously associated with sickness or disease. It feels like children are hosting parasites in their gums... Which is very irrational, of course.

Comment: Is that an actual skull or is it a model? It looks too shiny and has no lines or discolouration that one would normally expect to see on a "real" skull?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deciduous_teeth) on decidious teeth references the picture from [Gray's Anatomy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray%27s_Anatomy).

[image: Front view of skull.]

Google search also gives some references.

Scheme on [Colgate professional.](http://www.colgateprofessional.com/patienteducation/Developing-Teeth-Moving-From-Primary-To-Permanent/article)

[image: Permanent teeth]

[Article in dentist Rick Wilsond blog](http://rickwilsondmd.typepad.com/rick_wilson_dmds_blog/2011/01/dental-pulp-calcification-and-changes-with-age.html) featuring X-Ray picture from 9 year old:
[image]

And also child's skull from Hunterian Museum in London:

[image: Children's skull]

Okay I think it's enough for this answer.
So, I assume there're no obvious inaccuracies in the scary picture from question.

Comment: A side-by-side image of the same skull with and without the layer of bone removed to show the tooth buds would be a great addition to this already great answer.